# Definition of Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator using open balls or closed balls

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator is defined by

$$ Mf(x):= \sup_{B\ni x} \frac{1}{|B|} \int_{B} |f(y)| dy. $$

Here, the supremum is taken over balls $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which contain the point $x$ and $|B|$ denotes the measure of $B$.

If the balls in the definition is open, then we denote the operator $M_{o}$.

If the balls in the definition is closed, then we denote the operator $M_{c}$.

Can we say that $M_{o}=M_{c}$?

Comment: Where is the operator from? For example is $f$ continuous or just locally integrable?

Comment: $f$ is a locally integrable function.

Comment: measure 0 sets don't make a difference, so stop worrying

Comment: If you denote open balls by $B$, and their appropriate closed balls by $\overline{B}$, I think it will be enough to show that the term inside is equal in both cases. This is true simply because you are adding an integral on a zero measured set and $\vert B\vert = \vert \overline{B}\vert$.